# How to force SSL for Ruby on Rails Public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, https, public

I have a Unity Game in my public folder of my Ruby on Rails application.  It connects to my Rails API.  Even though the HTTP requests in the game go to my SSL API of my Rails app, my clients are skeptical because the URL doesnt say "Secure" like other websites.  Any way to make the public folder restricted to SSL protocol requests?

Comment: how are you hosting your app? are you on heroku?

Comment: Yeah I've got it on Heroku.  My Rails web app has the config.force_ssl = true, but that doesn't apply to the public folder, only controller routes

Comment: Are you running NGINX, or similar? That's where you need to enforce the SSL.

Comment: https on heroku is frustrating. i'll try to write up a full answer in a bit, but a quick point: make sure the link you're sharing with your clients starts with https://. i believe the default configuration supports secure AND insecure, so if you don't specify, it serves insecure.

Comment: @eiko I have the new distributed redirect URL go to the https version but I'm sure because this product is in commercial use, that some old users bookmarked the old http URL, trying to figure out a re-route.